# Redirect URL input errors that use $_GET

Tags: php

I have a form that a user can choose dates on to get the specific archive page. However when they get to that page, they can manually input values in the URL and get different results from the db. So far I've managed to redirect nearly all the errors except one, the URL looks like this `content.php?day=mon&year=2015&month=jan&week=wk1`. If a user enters values for day/year/month/week that aren't allowed they're redirected to `errors/wrong_url.php`. But if they alter the variable names themselves i.e day/year/month/week/.My redirection fails and the page loads normally but with errors. 
If the month and week varible names were altered, the redirection works.But if the year and day var names were altered the pages loads without content for var day and with content for var year.

```html
if(isset($_GET['year'])){

    $year =  preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $_GET['year']);
    $month =  preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $_GET['month']);
    $week =  preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $_GET['week']);
    $datefdr = $year."-".$month."-".$week;

    $page_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $day_pattern = '/id=[a-z]*/'; 
    $year_pattern = '/id=[0-9]*/'; 
    $month_pattern = '/id=[a-z]*/'; 
    $week_pattern = '/id=[a-z0-9]*/'; 

    if(isset($_GET['day'])){
        $category =  preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $_GET['day']);
        $days_list = array("mon", "tue", "wed", "thur", "fri", "sat", "sun");
        $year_list = array("2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021");
        $month_list = array("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec");
        $week_list = array("wk1", "wk2", "wk3", "wk4");

        if (preg_match($day_pattern, $page_url) && preg_match($year_pattern, $page_url) && preg_match($month_pattern, $page_url) && preg_match($week_pattern, $page_url)){
            if (in_array($year, $year_list) && in_array($month, $month_list) && in_array($week, $week_list) && in_array($category, $days_list)){
                switch ($category) {
                    case "monday":
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM vidz WHERE day='monday' AND datefdr='$datefdr'";
                        break;
                }
            }else{
                    header("Location:errors/wrong_url.php");
            }
        }else{
            header("Location:errors/wrong_url.php");
        }
        
    }
}else {
    $url_name = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $file_name = basename($url_name);
    $file_name = basename($url_name, ".php");

    switch ($file_name) {
        case "content":
            $query = "SELECT * FROM vidz WHERE day='content' AND datefdr='content'";
            break;
    }
    
}
```

I already have a JavaScript function that prevents the user from submitting an empty form. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you just need to check whether all the variables are present in the GET request, although empty, and if any one variable is not present (that is, it has been renamed or removed), then redirect to the error page. I mean, you are already checking for each variable individually with an if-else struct, but it would be better to check all vars were passed the get request together beforehand.

Comment: in `if `condition what do you mean by `&` this?

Comment: chonchol, by `&` i mean if all statements evaluate as true

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I had the arrangements all wrong.

```html
if(isset($_GET['day'])){
    $category = $_GET['day'];
    $year = $_GET['year'];
    $month = $_GET['month'];
    $week = $_GET['week'];
 $datefdr = $year."-".$month."-".$week;
    $days_list = array("mon", "tue", "wed", "thur", "fri", "sat", "sun");
    $year_list = array("2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021");
    $month_list = array("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec");
    $week_list = array("wk1", "wk2", "wk3", "wk4");

    if (in_array($year, $year_list) && in_array($month, $month_list) && in_array($week, $week_list) && in_array($category, $days_list)){
        switch ($category) {
            case "mon":
                $query = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE day='mon' AND datefdr='$datefdr'";
                break;
        }
    }else{
            header("Location:http://dundaah.com/errors/wrong_url.php");
    }
    
}else {
    if (isset($_GET['year']) || isset($_GET['month']) || isset($_GET['week'])) {
        header("Location:http://dundaah.com/errors/wrong_url.php");
    }else{
        $url_name = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
     $file_name = basename($url_name);
     $file_name = basename($url_name, ".php");

     switch ($file_name) {
         case "content":
             $query = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE day='content' AND datefdr='content'";
             break;
     }
     
    }

}
```